# A question about filtered colimits in a category of representations

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

For $k$ a field, are filtered colimits exact in the category $\mathbf{Rep}_k(G)$ of (finite-dimensional) $k$-representations of a group $G$? I can neither prove it nor find a counterexample.

Comment: There are not that many filtered colimits in the category of finite-dimensional representations to begin with. Did you mean to ask about the category of all representations?

Comment: @ZhenLin There aren't many? Why?...There is definitely something I am missing then.

Comment: If they exist then you would have infinite direct sums, but you don't.

Comment: ...Is this category not cocomplete?

Comment: The category of _finite-dimensional_ representations is not cocomplete, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

For the category of all representations, filtered colimits are indeed exact because the forgetful functor from representations to vector spaces has adjoints on both sides; the left adjoint is $V\mapsto V\times G$ and the right, $V\mapsto \text{Hom}(k[G],V)$. Since the forgetful functor is monadic and preserves colimits, it creates all colimits (and limits). Since the forgetful functor is also conservative, exactness of filtered colimits follows from the same fact for vector spaces.

Comment: You also need the fact that the forgetful functor is conservative.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that looks like it claims that you only need creation. Thanks.